# Google Sheets: "Bob Smith" --> "bsmith" formula?

Tags: google-sheets, string-concatenation

I'm trying to pull data from another Google Sheet to feed another Google Sheet. I need to pull from a full name field, which will have something like, "Bob Smith" and then I need to have it rewrite into the new Google Sheet as "bsmith".

Basically, "Get first letter of the first string, then concatenate the entire second string, and then make all lowercase."

So far I've gotten `=LEFT(A28,1)` working to grab the first letter of a string, but then not sure how to grab the second **word** and then concatenate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the 2nd word you need to `FIND()` the first space then read from that position + 1 to the end of the string using `MID()`.  `&` is used for concatenation.

```
=lower(left(A28,1) & mid(A28, find(" ", A28) + 1, len(A28)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this for a Google sheet specific solution:

```
  =LOWER(REGEXREPLACE(A2,"^(\w).*?(\w+$)","$1$2"))
```

It uses `REGEX`, a much more sophisticated engine and easily adaptable to variations  than `LEFT` and/or `MID`.

Comment: Thanks much! This worked perfectly as well, and I just had to put lower() around it.

Comment: I was only able to use this to pull from the a cell on the same sheet. How would this work for two different cells on different tabs? (i.e. On one Google Sheet, at the bottom I have a "Sheet1" and a Sheet2"

Comment: You mean first name is in one tab and second name is in second Street?

Comment: Image here: http://i.imgur.com/wcxmRZf.png  (The full name is in one cell on the PullingFromThisSheet and then the new concatenated string is in one cell DisplayingOnThisSheet

Comment: Enter the formula on the displaying on this sheet A2= `=LOWER(REGEXREPLACE('PullingFromThisSheet'!A2,"^(\w).*?(\w+$)","$1$2"))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154146/discussion-between-ahainen-and-anonymous).

Answer (score 0):

Shorter:

```
=lower(left(A28)&index(split(A28," "),2))
```

(Assumes only ever two words.)